# RPC server is unavailable 0x800706BA, while updating password for user in active directory

Tags: active-directory, rpc, directoryservices

I am using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement apis to create a new user/disable an account in Active Directory. When i am trying to create a new user, and set its password, m/c throws an exception with the message **The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)**. The following snippet is used to create and persist the user.

```
UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
user.GivenName = "Andrew";
user.Surname = "Green";
user.EmailAddress = "agreeen@gmail.com";
user.SamAccountName = "agreen";
user.Save();
user.SetPassword("Pqw^&12");
user.Save();
```

When i execute this, the code throws an exception as soon as it tries to set a password.
After a little search on the net, I tried out the following things.

- Since acct *agreen* gets created without password, there is no privilege or connection issue.
- I added *Windows Management Instrumentation(WMI)* as exception to the windows firewall on my AD machine
- I ensured that the following services *RPC Endpoint Mapper, Remote Procedure Call, Remote Registry* are running on the AD machine.
- Ensured that the account, that is used to connect to AD machine, has *Enable remote Control* checked
- I verified that port 135 is not blocked on AD machine

The setup that i have is, I have box *b1* running Microsoft Windows 7 Professional, which is trying to connect to a box *b2*, running Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 enterprise. The c# code is running on .Net4.5 framework on b1, and trying to create account on b2.

When i tried running the code from the same box(i.e. box with AD), I was able to successfully create the account with password, when i specified the ip address as localhost, but when i specified it as m/c ip address, it failed with the same exception

Please let me know what i am doing wrong.

Thanks

Vishva